# Why is process.nextTick() called three times?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

[image: confusing diagram of Node event loop]

If this picture is right, why is `process.nextTick()` called three times?

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)

> any time you call process.nextTick() in a given phase, all callbacks passed to process.nextTick() will be resolved before the event loop continues.

There're phrases in event loop ,

before entering next phrase, event loop will execute all `process.nextTick` callback first.

So it depends on which phase you're calling the `process.nextTick`

Here's an example

```
function case1() {
  setImmediate(() => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('nextTick')//before going next phase
    })
    console.log('Immediate')
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timer1') //another phase
  })
}

function case2() {
  setImmediate(() => {
    setImmediate(() => {
        console.log('Immediate2') //next event loop
    })
    console.log('Immediate')
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timer1') //another phase
  })
}
```

then I call them in read file callback to ensure they start at the same phase(poll phase).

```
const fs = require('fs);
```

case1 would be

```
fs.readFile('./package.json', ()=>{
  case1(); 
  //Immediate
  //nextTick
  //timer1
})
```

case2

```
fs.readFile('./package.json', ()=>{
  case2()
  //Immediate
  //timer1
  //Immediate2
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> `process.nextTick()` evaluates callbacks up to `process.maxDepth`

This is a failsafe to prevent the `process.nextTick()` callback queue from completely hogging the single available thread. In order to still attempt to clear the queue as quickly as possible (e.g. in the next tick) the callbacks are evaluated multiple times in a single event loop.

Imagine `process.maxDepth=1` and we call `process.nextTick()` and `setImmidiate()` ten times each. All of the callbacks will not be evaluated in a single tick of the event loop. The `process.nextTick()` callbacks will be evaluated in just over three executions of the event loop, while the `setImmidiate()` callbacks will take a full ten ticks to completely execute.